# If all men were good, there would be no wars

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

> If all men were good, there would be no wars.
>
> Some men are not good. Therefore, there will be wars.

I am confused on what sign to use on the some part.

Comment: That's not solid reasoning.  Given $A\implies B$ we can't conclude that $not \;A\implies not\; B$.

Comment: Besides what @lulu has pointed out, maybe, $\exists$?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use the [existential quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification).

Basically, the symbol $\exists$ is the same as saying "there exists," so if you say:
$$(\exists man)(\sim\text{good}(man))$$
You're basically saying, "there exists a man such that the man is not good." This is the same as saying "Some man is not good." Thus, using quantifiers, we use the existential quantifier $\exists$ to signify the words "there exists" or "some," which mean the same thing.

Also, as [@lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644505/translation-of-arguments-into-symbolic-logic#comment3354012_1644505) pointed out, your argument is not valid, but you can still write out the argument using quantifiers and logical symbols.